# How to disable default filtering in PrimeNG datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

PrimeNG datatable has an option `[filter]="true"` which enables an input on column header used to filter data. Additionally the API provides a callback `onFilter` fired when filtering data.

Typing into the provided input for filtering data causes the table to run filtering on data in the table. In the callback I reload my data filtered from server which cases the data to be filtered twice. Can I disable the default filtering and at the same time have the input field in column header and onFilter callback available?

Comment: Of course it is an option to write my own component which will handle sorting and/or filtering, but if it's possible I'd like to use DataTable featurs.

Comment: You can use column header template which can have input text box and a callback function when user types in it, in call back function you can filter or sort or load data from backend based on input text.